# Issue with Jquery find and replace content

Tags: jquery, html, css

Folks,
  Dealing with a simple issue of replacing a text on screen for every `span` with class "`reason`". I have tried both on load and ready events without any luck. My page looks something like this:

```
<div class="sp-body">
   <div>......</div>
   <div>......</div>
   <section>......</section>
   <div>
        <span class="reason ng-binding">Trying To Replace This Reason!!!</span>

   </div>
     .
     .
     .
     .
```

What I have tried so far: 
Approach 1:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    //alert("JQuery Version: " + jQuery.fn.jquery);  //This alert works
    jQuery(".reason").each(function() {
        console.log("Found span class");
           $(this).text("Replacing with this!!!!");
         });
    console.log("After.......................");
});
```

Approach 2:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    //alert("JQuery Version: " + jQuery.fn.jquery);  //This alert works
    jQuery(".reason").each(function() {
        console.log("Found span class");
           $(this).text("Replacing with this!!!!");
         });
    console.log("After.......................");
});
```

PS: Page is generated using JSF and AngularJS (I don't think it matters on generated HTML)

Comment: What does it print if you run `console.log(jQuery(".reason"))` ?

Comment: Both work fine for me.

Comment: @spencer.sm It prints [object object]

Comment: The second one works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/z3qp821u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me ! What's the exact issue ?

```js
$("span.reason").each(function(){
  
  $(this).text("Replacing with this !");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp-body">
   <div>......</div>
   <div>......</div>
   <section>......</section>
   <div>
        <span class="reason ng-binding">Trying To Replace This Reason!!!</span>

   </div>
   <div>
        <span class="reason ng-binding">Trying To Replace This Reason!!!</span>

   </div>
   <div>
        <span class="reason ng-binding">Trying To Replace This Reason!!!</span>

   </div>
   <div>
        <span class="reason ng-binding">Trying To Replace This Reason!!!</span>

   </div>
```

Comment: I agree, it works fine but something else it causing it not to work in my application.

Comment: `$("span.reason").text("Replacing with this !");` first try this alone without using each funciton. If it not works then problem is might be with jQuery version which you are including.